# Stuck on class type redefinition error despite using include guards and pragma once

Tags: c++, class, header, redefinition

I am getting two class type redefinition errors in 2 of my .cpp files in my c++ project. I am using Visual Studio 2017. I've scoured the internet looking for a solution and found a bunch of people saying to use include guards and #pragma once. I put include guards in my header files but I am still getting class redefinition error in the .cpp files. I also tried putting #pragma once at the top of the all the files in my project. Here is the code in the parent class(the assignment this is for deals with inheritance)

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Members.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Members
{
protected:
    string first;
    string last;
    int ID;
public:
    Members() {};

    Members(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, int idNum)
    {
        first = firstName;
        last = lastName;
        ID = idNum;
    }

    void printMember() const
    {
        cout << "First Name is:" << first << " Last Name is:" << last << " 
ID is:" << ID << endl;
}

void readWriteMembers(ifstream& instream, ofstream& outstream)
{
    string x;
    for (int i = 0; instream.good(); i++)
    {
        getline(instream, x);
        outstream << x;
    }
}

string getFirstName()
{
    return first;
}

void setFirstName(string firstName)
{
    first = firstName;
}

string getLastName()
{
    return last;
}

void setLastName(string lastName)
{
    last = lastName;
}

int getID()
{
    return ID;
}

void setID(int id)
{
    ID = id;
}
};
```

And here is the code for the child class.

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Faculty.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Faculty:public Members
{
private:
    double salary;
public:
    Faculty() {};

    Faculty(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, int idNum, double theSalary) :Members(firstName,lastName,idNum)
{
    salary = theSalary;
}

void printMember()
{
    cout << "The faculty member name is:" << first << " " << last << " The id is:" << ID << " and the salary is:" << salary << endl;
}

double getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}

void setSalary(double theSalary)
{
    salary = theSalary;
}
void readWriteMembers(ifstream& instream)
{
    ofstream faculty_output;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string id;
    string salary;
    faculty_output.open("FacultyOutput.txt");
    for (int i = 0; instream.good(); i++)
    {
        if (instream.get() == 'f')
        {
            instream.ignore(1);
            instream >> firstname;
            instream >> lastname;
            instream >> id;
            instream >> salary;
            cout << "Faculty name:" << firstname << " " << lastname << "id is:" << id << " Salary is:" << salary << endl;

        }
    }
    faculty_output.close();
}
};
```

If it will help, here is the code for the two corresponding header files.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MEMBERS_H
#define MEMBERS_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Members
{
protected:
    string first;
    string last;
    int ID;
public:

    Members() {};
Members(const string& firstName, const string& lastName, int idNum) {};
void printMember() const {};
void readWriteMembers(ifstream& instream, ofstream& outstream);
string getFirstName();
void setFirstName(string firstName);
string getLastName();
void setLastName(string lastName);
int getID();
void setID(int id);
};
#endif
```

And the header file for the child class.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FACULTY_H
#define FACULTY_H
#include "Members.h"
using namespace std;
class Faculty:public Members
{
private:
double salary;
public:
Faculty() {};
Faculty(const string& firstName, string& lastName, int id, double salary) 
{};
void printMember() {};
void readWriteMembers(ifstream& instream) {};
double getSalary() {};
void setSalary(double theSalary) {};
};
#endif
```

Comment: Fixed problem. Was not aware you couldn't declare a class twice.